# Database access on other machine

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm working on a program that will work very nicely with a database structure and using mysql. I could easy do this with a common server and common database. However I'm looking for a way to have my client(s) use the program on an offline machine without having to install any database managing software.

Basically I want the installation to set up the necessary tables on their machine and have them fill in the database with information relevant to them. Before I start though I wanted to know if this was possible to connect to and manage a database through a C# application with out installing sql software.

Comment: Do you have to use MySQl?  You can use [SqlLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) which supports local DBs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact).

[SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) is another option.

Both of these can be deployed with your application and need no separate configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible. How to do it exactly depends on the database connection approach you're using. For example, [this approach shows how to use DataReaders](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_data_reader.html). That's a very old approach. Modern approaches are recommended to use [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx), which can be configured to access remotely by setting up a DataContext to point to an external resource.

Basically, wherever you can define a connection string to connect to a DB, you can make that string point locally or externally. An external resource must obviously be available through some URL in order to connect, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can not connect to a mysql database without installing mysql.

However you can use in process database like sqlite or Compact SQL. They are not traditional server, but rather a library that keeps the database in a local file.